# NDK Clang error: undefined reference to 'localeconv'

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to build C++ NDK lib inside Android Studio.I have an external lib called [json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) and the Clang compiler faild on localeconv.

> json.hpp:11867: error: undefined reference to 'localeconv'

The locale.h header exists and located inside ndk dir sysroot/usr/include.

My toolchain looks like this:

**Gradle:** (Showing only the part relevant to NDK)

```
 externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {

            arguments "-DANDROID_PLATFORM_LEVEL=${platformVersion}",
                    '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'

        }
    }
```

**Cmake**

```
 set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=gnu11 -Wall")
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -frtti  -fexceptions  -Wall")

  //'native-lib' is the final .so that's packaged into apk
       target_link_libraries(native-lib
                   OPENAL
                   FREETYPE
                   android
                    EGL
                    ${OPENGL_LIB}
                    log
                    m
                    z
                    atomic
                    gnustl_static
                    )
```

**And here is the linker command line:**

> [1/1] Linking CXX shared library
>   ........\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so
>   FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . &&
>   D:\Android\android-sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe
>   --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=D:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
>   --sysroot=D:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem D:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
>   -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -std=c++11 -frtti  -fexceptions  -Wall -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot D:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm
>   -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so

**The complete error:**

> "D:/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a"
>   && cd ." D:\XXXXX\XXXXXX\windows....\thirdparty\json/json.hpp:11867:
>   **error: undefined reference to 'localeconv'** clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. :app:externalNativeBuildDebug
>   FAILED

The target SDK is 21.Minimum SDK is 19.NDK Version: 15.0.4075724

The same code base is compiled fine in Visual Studio Android project which uses the same toolchain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is - NDK version for SDK 19 doesn't implement the whole C++11 standard in the STL. `locale.h`  header has stubs for `localeconv()` method, but the library doesn't implement it.The closest Android SDK that implement  `localeconv()` is SDK 21.This is implicitly stated in the header `<locale.h>`

```
struct lconv* localeconv(void) __INTRODUCED_IN(21) __VERSIONER_NO_GUARD;

#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 21
locale_t duplocale(locale_t) __INTRODUCED_IN(21);
void freelocale(locale_t) __INTRODUCED_IN(21);
locale_t newlocale(int, const char*, locale_t) __INTRODUCED_IN(21);
#endif /* __ANDROID_API__ >= 21 */

char* setlocale(int, const char*);

#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 21
locale_t uselocale(locale_t) __INTRODUCED_IN(21);
#endif /* __ANDROID_API__ >= 21 */


#define LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE __BIONIC_CAST(reinterpret_cast, locale_t, -1L)

__END_DECLS

#endif /* _LOCALE_H_ */
```

Comment: I faced the same problem with Lua-5.3.4 library which is using locale.h.  I could not understand the solution here, could you please explain.           Are you suggesting to increase the android minSDKVersion to 21  in the APP build.gradle ?

Comment: SDK 19 doesn't contain that feature. Use newer SDK

Comment: how to use newer SDK, by changing the minimum sdk version ?

Comment: @madanV  That's right. Install and use higher version of the SDK

Answer (score 0):

For me, trying to use Lua 5.4.0, I have to define the API level to 21

Cmake file as:

```
set(ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL    21)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and unfortunaletly changing API level couldn't work for me --I was working with an old tablet which runs API16. You can try *Crystax NDK* or you can write an ugly function that mimics the `localeconv()`. The latter had solved my problem since I was building Lua for Android Terminal Emulator for hobby.